# What is the relationship between canvas and matrix in Android?

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, bitmap, concatenation

I read this canvas overview :

> The Canvas class holds the "draw" calls. To draw something, you need 4
>   basic components: A Bitmap to hold the pixels, a Canvas to host the
>   draw calls (writing into the bitmap), a drawing primitive (e.g. Rect,
>   Path, text, Bitmap), and a paint (to describe the colors and styles
>   for the drawing).

Can anyone explain the canvas more clearly?

And I am confused about the relationship between the canvas and matrix. Does the canvas takes the transformations from the matrix?
And I want to know if below function affect on the canvas?

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
```

In other words, is the canvas matrix different from the bitmap matrix?

I asked this, because when I'm using `canvas.drawBitmap` and then using `canvas.concat()`  and then drawing any object, this object takes same transformations on canvas, so I think the canvas and bitmap have the same matrix!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are different. When using the canvas to draw a bitmap providing a matrix, internally, the provided matrix are concatenated to the current canvas matrix.

In other words, calling `canvas.drawBitmap(rectBitmap, matrix, paint);` has the same effect of:

```
    canvas.save();
    canvas.concat(matrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(rectBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    canvas.restore();
```

This explain why your object is taking the same transformations because you are calling `canvas.concat(matrix);` and after that drawing the object.

Comment: But if I don't use "canvas.concat", is the "canvas.drawBitmap" calling "canvas.concat" internally ?

Comment: and which matrix concatenated with other ?

Comment: It first saves the current canvas matrix to a stack, then concats the provided matrix to the current canvas matrix, after that draws the bitmap and finally pop the saved matrix making it the current canvas matrix. This way, next drawing operation is unaffected by the matrix you provided to `drawBitmap`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand yet :( how the next operations not effected while the original canvas was changed as you mentioned "then concats the provided matrix to the current canvas matrix"

Comment: Because before the concat operation it saves the canvas matrix to a stack and after that it restores the saved matrix.